# Add New Kernel Parameter To Custom Linux Image Generated By Yocto

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, yocto, procps

I am experimenting with [Yocto project](https://www.yoctoproject.org/) for generating custom Linux images for my embedded devices.

I have a requirement to add a persistent custom kernel parameter to `/etc/sysctl.conf` of the generated image.

i.e.

```
kernel.core_pipe_limit = 1
```

`/etc/sysctl.conf` is generated by `procps` package that comes with `Yocto` base system (`meta/recipes-extended/procps/procps/sysctl.conf`). However, I believe editing the `sysctl.conf` in the base system is not the recommended approach.

I am using a new layer for defining my custom configurations. I hope there is a way to apply a patch to a base package via a custom layer after deploying the base layer.

How can I do this?

---

I am aware how to persistently change a kernel variable by updating `/etc/sysctl.conf` (or, preferably, `/etc/sysctl.d/xxx.conf`). My question is, how to generate the Linux image with the necessary update applied?

Comment: Don't you have `/etc/sysctl.d/` ? Check what your `sysctl --system` does.

Comment: Yes there is `/etc/sysctl.d`. But what is the correct way to add an entry even there, in the final image built by Yocto ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add something like this in image recipe or `local.conf`:

```
set_kernel_opt(){
    mkdir -p ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc/sysctl.d
    echo 'kernel.core_pipe_limit = 1' > ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc/sysctl.d/kernel_core_pipe_limit.conf
}

ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND += "set_kernel_opt;"
```

---

If you want to override `/etc/sysctl.conf` file, you can create a `meta-custom/recipes-extended/procps/procps_%.bbappend` file with:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
```

Then create a folder `meta-custom/recipes-extended/procps/files` and copy your custom `sysctl.conf` file in it.

---

Finally you can create a `meta-custom/recipe-custom/custom-config/custom-config.bb` recipe with:

```
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

SRC_URI = " \
   file://kernel_core_pipe_limit.conf \
"

PV = "1.0"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

inherit allarch

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/sysctl.d
    install -m 0644 ${B}/kernel_core_pipe_limit.conf ${D}${sysconfdir}/sysctl.d/
}

do_configure[noexec] = "1"
do_compile[noexec] = "1"
```

And copy your `kernel_core_pipe_limit.conf` in `meta-custom/recipe-custom/custom-config/files/`

Answer (score 2):

The answer up there are wrong in my opinion. There is already a recipe providing sysctl.conf. It is `procps`. What you need to do is override the default configuration with a bbappend. More about append files on the [online Yocto documention](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#append-bbappend-files)

Create a **procps** folder, **procps_%.bbappend** and **systctl.conf** in recipes-extended in your layer such as

```
meta-my-layer/recipes-extended/
└── procps
    ├── files
    │   └── sysctl.conf
    └── procps_%.bbappend
```

**procps_%.bbappend**:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"`
```

(example of) **sysctl.conf**:

```
fs.protected_hardlinks = 1
fs.protected_symlinks = 1
```

In case you want to keep default configuration and append to it, you only need a **do_install_append** step with an echo appending your text.

Comment: This solution has the benefit that it exactly documents the changes from the default file provided by the original recipe! Kudos!

Comment: I gave 3 solutions, in the middle the procps bbappend :)

Answer (score 1):

Just create a file with `.conf` extension under `/etc/sysctl.d`.

```
echo 'kernel.core_pipe_limit = 1' > /etc/sysctl.d/bla_bla_change_kernel_core_pipe_limit.conf
```

From [man sysctl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sysctl.8.html):

```
 --system
              Load settings from all system configuration files. Files are
              read from directories in the following list in given order
              from top to bottom.  Once a file of a given filename is
              loaded, any file of the same name in subsequent directories is
              ignored.
              /run/sysctl.d/*.conf
              /etc/sysctl.d/*.conf
              /usr/local/lib/sysctl.d/*.conf
              /usr/lib/sysctl.d/*.conf
              /lib/sysctl.d/*.conf
              /etc/sysctl.conf
```

The `sysctl --system` *should* be called on system startup. On systems with systemd this is done via `systemd-sysctl.service` service. Thus it should load all the `/etc/sysctl.d`. The syntax is the same as `/etc/sysct.conf` syntax files.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But how can I relate this to my exact problem? How to make `Yocto` do this? i.e. create the custom Linux image with `sysctl.conf` (or `sysctl.d/xxx.conf`) properly updated.